# Fork/Join example with GPars

Tags: groovy, fork-join, gpars

I found an example for fork/join in GPars here: [Fork/Join](http://www.gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html#dataParallelism_fork-join)

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.runForkJoin
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool
withPool() {
    println """Number of files: ${
        runForkJoin(new File("./src")) {file ->
            long count = 0
            file.eachFile {
                if (it.isDirectory()) {
                    println "Forking a child task for $it"
                    forkOffChild(it)           //fork a child task
                } else {
                    count++
                }
            }
            return count + (childrenResults.sum(0))
            //use results of children tasks to calculate and store own result
        }
    }"""
}
```

It works and returns the correct number of files, but unfortunately I don't understand this line:

```
return count + (childrenResults.sum(0))
```

How exactly work `count` and `childrenResult`?
Why is a `0` passed as a parameter to `sum()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not much familiar with GPars, but the link you provided says it is a [Divide-and-Conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) algorithm and clarifies a bit more what's implicit later on, explaining that `forkOffChild()` does not wait -- instead `getChildrenResults()` does.

You may find easier to understand the provided alternative approach in the same page, that uses a more Java-ish style, if you're more familiar to that.

`childrenResults` results in calling the method [`getChildrenResults()`](http://gpars.org/1.0.0/groovydoc/groovyx/gpars/forkjoin/AbstractForkJoinWorker.html#getChildrenResults%28%29), this is the "join" in "Fork/Join", it waits for all children to finish and then returns a list with the results of them (or re-throws any exception a children may have thrown).

`0` is just the initial value for the sum. If `childrenResult` is empty, that's what gets summed to `count`:

```
groovy:000> [].sum(1)
===> 1
groovy:000> [1].sum(1)
===> 2
```